# SPSS - DO IF function with missing values and multiple compute statements

Tags: if-statement, spss, missing-data

I want to compute multiple new variables for cases that are NOT missing multiple values. For those cases where `Var.1` to `Var.10` are missing, then I want the computed vars `A, B, C` to be SYSMIS.

Example code:

```
DO IF (NOT MISSING(Var.1 to Var.10)).
COMPUTE A=0.
COMPUTE B=0.
COMPUTE C=0.
END IF.
```

This produces multiple errors:
DO IF - The number of arguments to a function was incorrect.
END IF - The command does not follow an unclosed DO IF command.

I've tried removing periods and adding/removing parentheses to no effect. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first count the missing values in your multiple set:

```
count Nmiss=Var.1 to Var.10 (missing).
```

Now you can use the count in your `if` statement:

```
do if Nmiss=0.
...
```

(or `do if Nmiss<10.` - depending on your exact goal)

Comment: Equivalently you can use `COMPUTE Nmiss = NMISS(Var.1 TO Var.10).`